# Multi-line bar chart in plotly library python

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly-python

I am using plotly to plot multi-color bar chart from my dataset. I have a transactional dataset and I am going to plot following figure:

[image]

I explain now what I want to do. For an selected item I want to show such a figure. Let's say for item number 'xxx' I want to show above multi-color bar chart figure. In the y-axis I want to show each year and for each year(for each bar) I also want to show from which vendors I purchased that item. Each colored cell represents a vendor. And total spend for each vendor as shown on each colored cell. In the x-axis I want to show how much in total I spend for the item during each year. I want to do that in plotly library.

My code:

```
 fig = px.bar(a, x='Year', y='Spend', color='Vendor_Name', 
                                                 barmode='stack')
 fig.update_traces(marker_line_width=0)
 fig.show()
```

Result:

[image]

I couldn't be able to show the number in each cell as shown in the abovest figure. I couldn't do same thing for my result.

Comment: Have you already written any code? What specific problem are you facing?

Comment: Sorry maybe my explanation isn't goof enough, I added my current code and result to be more clear for you @Pascalco

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at:[plotly's website](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-direct-labels) or [Geeks for geeks website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-stacked-bar-chart-in-python-plotly/)

In these links you'll find an assortment of different code combinations and libraries you may need to import to successfully layer and plot the values.

I would also suggest playing around with the different libraries and combining/manipulating the different code structures from the website to see if you can get the values to appear. For example, some of the code explicitly labels the data by the axis or relies on the fig.update_layout to generate different visuals.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Matthew Hockert, II will try with that way